# first two results from ls command

Tags: linux, search, limit, ls

I am using `ls -l -t` to get a list of files in a directory ordered by time.

I would like to limit the search result to the top 2 files in the list.
Is this possible?
I've tried with grep and I struggled.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You can pipe it into `head`:

```
ls -l -t | head -3
```

Will give you top 3 lines (2 files and the total).

This will just give you the first 2 lines of files, skipping the size line:

```
ls -l -t | tail -n +2 | head -2
```

`tail` strips the first line, then `head` outputs the next 2 lines.

Comment: This will take insanely long when you have a lot of files inside that folder. Is there a way to REALLY just show the first 3 lines without Linux running through the entire folder first ?

Comment: @Sliq - because the goal is to find the two _newest_ files, you must look at every file in the directory no matter what method you use. If you were writing lower-level code you could do it in a single pass, rather than sorting, but you'd _still_ need to look at all of the files.

Comment: I'm really sorry I downvoted this. I was working on another window, but I mouse acted up and I accidentally hit the down button.

Comment: how can i remove the first two results got by "ls" to avoid removing them with pipe ( | xargs rm -rf )

Answer (score 10):

To avoid dealing with the top output line you can reverse the sort and get the last two lines

```
ls -ltr | tail -2
```

This is pretty safe, but depending what you'll do with those two file entries after you find them, you should read [Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) on the problems with using `ls` to get files and file information.

Answer (score 8):

Or you could try just this

```
ls -1 -t | head -2
```

The -1 switch skips the title line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `head` command to grab only the first two lines of output:

```
ls -l -t | head -2
```

Comment: This will not give you the top 2 files, it will provide the size of the listing plus the first file listed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pipe through head.

> ls -l -t | head -n 3

will output the two first results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ls -td -- * | head -n 2
```